# Is there a way to give each line a separate style when wrapping a textarea's placeholder?

Tags: javascript, css, textarea

I'm developing a simple board with React.

However, I am working on a textarea and I want to change the font-weight of each after a line break for the placeholder.

I know how to handle a line break, but I don't know how to give it a style after that.

Is there any way?

```js
<textarea id='contents' placeholder="Title&#13;&#10; ex)Date,Content..."></textarea>
```

I'm `&#13;&#10;` As a standard, I would like to change the title's font-weight from 700 ex to 400.
Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

With `<textarea>` I don't think this is possible in any way.
You can however use [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content)

Answer (score 0):

**[sandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-rosalind-rkv8n7?file=/src/App.js)**

```
::placeholder {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```